# How do you find the form name in a Django unittest?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-unittest

How do you find what Django name's a form within its context, so that you can assert tests on the form?

I have a simple unittest like:

```
def test_stuff(self):

    client = Client()
    response = client.post('/admin/app/model/add', {'name': 'Some Name'}
    self.assertFormError(response, 'what is this?!?!?', 'name', 'This name already exists')
```

Django's unittest framework provides methods to specifically test form fields...but they all require a form name. However, when testing admin views, these are auto-generated, so I don't know them, much less can I hard-code them inside a unittest.

How do I find this name? Attempting to print response.context shows an enormous amount of data, so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Are you just wanting to to unit test a form you're using in your ModelAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1499) I think the form is available in the context as `adminform`.

Comment: I already thought of this, but unfortunately it's expecting something else. It gives me the error "The form 'adminform' was not used to render the response". The actual form instance is at adminform.form, but I get a similar error message for that too.